# How do i derive the token id using googlelogin? Kept getting JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed error

Tags: jwt, google-oauth

I am using @react-oauth/google package to set up a google login authentication button.
On successful login, I can use jwtdecode to obtain the user details from the response credentials. However, I do not know how to derive the token id from the credentials. See my code below. I am getting a jwt malformed error.

```
<GoogleLogin
                    
onSuccess={googleSuccess}
onError={() => {
console.log('Login Failed');
}}
/>


  const googleSuccess = (res) => {
    
    const result = jwtDecode(res.credential)
    console.log(result)
    const token = result.sub
    
    try {
      dispatch({ type: AUTH, data: { result, token} });

      navigateTo('/')
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

i managed to solve it. res.credential itself is the token. below is revised code.

```
const googleSuccess = (res) => {
    console.log(res);
    const result = jwtDecode(res.credential);
    console.log(result);
    const token = res.credential;

    try {
      dispatch({ type: AUTH, data: { result, token } });

      navigateTo("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```